# Rewriting a limit of a cumulative distribution function $F_X$

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

$$\lim_{\varepsilon->0^+} (F_X(a) - F_X(a-\varepsilon)) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } F_X \text{ is continuous in } a \\ \text{jump of } F_X & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

My question is if

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+} F_X(a-\varepsilon) = \lim_{x\to a^-} F_X(x) \tag{1}$$

so that the limit above is

$$\lim_{x->a^-} (F_X(a) - F_X(x)) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } F_X \text{ is continuous in } a \\ \text{jump of } F_X & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

In point(1) is the subscript "x" a capital letter or not,  $\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} F_X(x)$ or with capital letter, $\lim\limits_{X\to a^-} F_X(x)$ and why?

EDIT: Just in case my doubt isn't clear enough, I'd like to know if this equality holds,

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+} F_X(a-\varepsilon) = \lim_{x\to a^-} F_X(x) $$

Comment: Capital $X$ is the random variable; lowercase $x$ is a particular value of that random variable. You're examining what happens to the CDF of the random variable when the particular value approaches some number, so you would write the limit with $x\to\text{number}$.